# In FFMPEG's H.265 encoder, which CRF value leads to "visually lossless" results?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, h.264, h.265

I am trying to shrink some videos from 1920x1080 to 1280x720 and to achieve a reasonable compromise between video quality and file size. I have decided to give FFMPEG's H.265 encoder a try, and now would like to know which CRF value I should use to get "visually lossless" results.

I know that this term may be misleading, but I have taken it from [FFMPEG's H.264 documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). In the section about the CRF value:

> Consider 17 or 18 to be visually lossless or nearly so; it should look the same or nearly the same as the input but it isn't technically lossless.

Furthermore, in [FFMPEG's H.265 documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265), in the section about the CRF value:

> The default is 28, and it should visually correspond to libx264 video at CRF 23, but result in about half the file size.

So I have learned that a H.265 CRF 28 should produce roughly the same visual results as a H.264 CRF 23.

**Question:**

Does that mean that a H.265 CRF 22 should produce roughly the same visual results as a H.264 CRF 17?

In other words, is the following statement correct: If I encode a video with H.264 with a CRF of `N`, do I get the same visual result if I encode the same video with H.265 with a CRF of `N+5`, independent of `N`? Or does that formula only apply for `N=28` and `N=23`, respectively, since this is the example the FFMPEG H.265 documentation gives?

Comment: The suggestion provided by @Gyan is approx 21 here - https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/what-crf-or-settings-i-should-choose-for-h265-in-order-to-achieve-a-similiar-qua

Answer (score 0):

considering that in ffmpeg every +6 in crf means half the bitrate
and considering that hevc is 50% more efficient than avc
a crf of 23-24 will lead to visually-lossless compression in ffmpeg with libx265.